# Error While Running W3af

Tags: source-packages

Hey Every0ne <<< Got A problem And i Hope You Help Me With :( !

When i Just Trying To run W3af GUI Or The Console , i Got This :-

```
    Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pdfminer/pdfminer-20110515.tar.gz#md5=f3905f801ed469900d9e5af959c7631a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pdfminer/) (63c353dd799302b844ab40578b840fb9) doesn't match the expected hash f3905f801ed469900d9e5af959c7631a!
  Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pdfminer/pdfminer-20110515.tar.gz#md5=f3905f801ed469900d9e5af959c7631a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pdfminer/)
```

Can You Help Me With ,,, Please :"(

Answer (score 0):

Try installing PDFMiner and w3af from the Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge w3af
sudo apt install python-pdfminer w3af
```